What is the difference between sys.configuration and sys.database_scoped_configuration for Max degree of parallelism?
I'm trying to get the current max degree of parallelism in a database so I came across two ways of doing it the problem is I get different results
When I run
SELECT value_in_use FROM sys.configurations WHERE description LIKE '%max%%parallelism%'

I get
0

But when I run
SELECT value FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations WHERE name = 'MAXDOP'

I get
8

Why do I get different results? What are the differences between them?
As a side note, I've been taking a look at this because of the N limit issue

Do you mean sys.configurations  (with an s on the end) ?

I'm guessing so you can override server config with specific database ones?

Check the relevant documentation.

sp_configure is only supported with Azure SQL Managed Instance where you can do configuration at the server level with it. On Azure SQL Database you do configurations at the database level so you should rely on the information retrieved from sys.database_scoped_configurations.
Configurations changes you usually do on SQL Server with sp_configure, you have to do them with ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION statement on Azure SQL Database. MaxDop is changed with that ALTER DATABASE statement on Azure SQL and you get confirmation of changes made by querying only the sys.database_scoped_configurations DMV.
